# Bottom native button

Tags: flutter

I'm sorry because I don't speak English very well. I would like to know if it is possible to control the bottom 3 native buttons of Android phone? Example When I am in the application, if I click on the home button or another can I write something in the console or another action before my application closes or even program that I am redirected to the page HomePage before my application closes?

Answer (score 0):

For example, regarding the back button, you can control it with `WillPopScope` : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html